# Chartjs Polar Area Chart: Category missing

Tags: chart.js, polar-coordinates

I just can't figure out why is there allways at least one category missing from my chart:

[image: Polar area chart with missing category D2]

This does not happen when I switch chart type to type:'pie'.

Please find my code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 40%;">
      <canvas id="polarAreaChart " width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("polarAreaChart ");

            var polarAreaChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'polarArea',
                options: {
                        legend: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'bottom',
                        }
                },
                data: {
                    labels: ["D1","D2","D3"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Dimensiones',
                        data: [40, 20, 40],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#f8b195",
                            "#c06c84",
                            "#6c5b7b"
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            });
        </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any comments will help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was just a bug.
Solved it by using a more recent version of Chartjs:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js